# Understanding different results of optim() and lm()

Tags: r

Given:

```
   set.seed(1001)
   outcome<-rnorm(1000,sd = 1)
   covariate<-rnorm(1000,sd = 1)
```

log-likelihood of normal pdf:

```
   loglike <- function(par, outcome, covariate){
               cov <- as.matrix(cbind(1, covariate))
               xb <- cov * par
              (- 1/2* sum((outcome - xb)^2))
   }
```

optimize:

```
                  opt.normal <- optim(par = 0.1,fn = loglike,outcome=outcome,cov=covariate, method = "BFGS",  control = list(fnscale = -1),hessian = TRUE)
```

However I get different results when running an simple OLS. However maximizing log-likelihhod and minimizing OLS should bring me to a similar estimate. I suppose there is something wrong with my optimization.

```
                  summary(lm(outcome~covariate))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Umm several things...  Here's a proper working likelihood function (with names x and y):

```
loglike =
function(par,x,y){cov = cbind(1,x); xb = cov %*% par;(-1/2)*sum((y-xb)^2)}
```

Note use of *matrix multiplication* operator.

You were also only running it with one `par` parameter, so it was not only broken because your loglike was doing element-element multiplication, it was only returning one value too.

Now compare optimiser parameters with lm coefficients:

```
opt.normal <- optim(par = c(0.1,0.1),fn = loglike,y=outcome,x=covariate, method = "BFGS",  control = list(fnscale = -1),hessian = TRUE)
opt.normal$par
```

> ```
> [1]  0.02148234 -0.09124299
> ```

```
 summary(lm(outcome~covariate))$coeff
```

> ```
>                Estimate Std. Error    t value    Pr(>|t|)
> (Intercept)  0.02148235 0.03049535  0.7044466 0.481319029
> covariate   -0.09124299 0.03049819 -2.9917515 0.002842011
> ```

shazam.

Helpful hints: create data that you know the right answer for - eg `x=1:10; y=rnorm(10)+(1:10)` so you know the slope is 1 and the intercept 0. Then you can easily see which of your things are in the right ballpark. Also, run your `loglike` function on its own to see if it behaves as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you will find it usefull to see the difference between these two methods from my code. I programmed it the following way.

```
data.matrix <- as.matrix(hprice1[,c("assess","bdrms","lotsize","sqrft","colonial")])
loglik <- function(p,z){
  beta <- p[1:5]
  sigma <- p[6]
  y <- log(data.matrix[,1])
  eps <- (y - beta[1] - z[,2:5] %*% beta[2:5])
  -nrow(z)*log(sigma)-0.5*sum((eps/sigma)^2)
}
p0 <- c(5,0,0,0,0,2)
m <- optim(p0,loglik,method="BFGS",control=list(fnscale=-1,trace=10),hessian=TRUE,z=data.matrix)


rbind(m$par,sqrt(diag(solve(-m$hessian))))
```

And for the lm() method I find this

```
m.ols <- lm(log(assess)~bdrms+lotsize+sqrft+colonial,data=hprice1)
summary(m.ols)
```

Also if you would like to estimate the elasticity of assessed value with respect to the lotsize or calculate a 95% confidence interval
for this parameter, you could use the following

```
elasticity.at.mean <- mean(hprice1$lotsize) * m$par[3]
var.coefficient <- solve(-m$hessian)[3,3]
var.elasticity <- mean(hprice1$lotsize)^2 * var.coefficient
# upper bound
elasticity.at.mean + qnorm(0.975)* sqrt(var.elasticity)
# lower bound
elasticity.at.mean + qnorm(0.025)* sqrt(var.elasticity)
```

A more simple example of the optim method is given below for a binomial distribution.

```
loglik1 <- function(p,n,n.f){
  n.f*log(p) + (n-n.f)*log(1-p)
}

m <- optim(c(pi=0.5),loglik1,control=list(fnscale=-1),
           n=73,n.f=18)
m

m <- optim(c(pi=0.5),loglik1,method="BFGS",hessian=TRUE,
           control=list(fnscale=-1),n=73,n.f=18)
m

pi.hat <- m$par
```

numerical calculation of s.d

```
rbind(pi.hat=pi.hat,sd.pi.hat=sqrt(diag(solve(-m$hessian))))
```

analytical

```
rbind(pi.hat=18/73,sd.pi.hat=sqrt((pi.hat*(1-pi.hat))/73))
```

Or this code for the normal distribution.

```
loglik1 <- function(p,z){
  mu <- p[1]
  sigma <- p[2]

  -(length(z)/2)*log(sigma^2) - sum(z^2)/(2*sigma^2) + 
    (mu*sum(z)/sigma^2) - (length(z)*mu^2)/(2*sigma^2)
}

m <- optim(c(mu=0,sigma2=0.1),loglik1,
           control=list(fnscale=-1),z=aex)
```